# Unity offset parallax fails on web builds

Tags: 2d, textures, parallax, unity-game-engine

thanks in advance for helping me out.

I'm wrapping up work on a 2D platformer that has a background parallax effect using a texture offset on five different layers. The two cloud layers just have their offset scrolling over time, and the three ground layers scroll based on the camera position. This all works perfectly in Unity and in the PC build and looks great.

However, on the Unity Web Player and webGL builds, instead of the texture wrapping, it looks like this:

[I'm new here, so I can't embed images yet it seems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MX5yl.png)

I have no idea what is causing the problem, but instead of wrapping around and acting like a conveyor belt, it just streaks like that. Here is my parallax code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class sceneryParallax : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField]
private Transform cameraTransform;

[SerializeField]
private Renderer renderBGFar;

[SerializeField]
private Renderer renderBGMid;

[SerializeField]
private Renderer renderBGNear;

public float offsetFar;
public float offsetMid;
public float offsetNear;

void Update () {

    float xOffset = cameraTransform.position.x;

    Vector2 farOffset = new Vector2((xOffset / offsetFar) % 1.0f, 0.0f);
    Vector2 midOffset = new Vector2((xOffset / offsetMid) % 1.0f, 0.0f);
    Vector2 nearOffset = new Vector2((xOffset / offsetNear) % 1.0f, 0.0f);


    renderBGFar.material.mainTextureOffset = farOffset;
    renderBGMid.material.mainTextureOffset = midOffset;
    renderBGNear.material.mainTextureOffset = nearOffset;
}
}
```

Also, here is a screen of my texture setup:

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fic2.png)

Sorry if there are any formatting problems! I really appreciate any help you can offer. If you need more information, let me know!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your texture wrapping mode is set to clamp, it will reuse the last available pixel. It sounds like texture mode *repeat* is what you need, opposed to clamping, per the documentation:

> This is useful for preventing wrapping artifacts when mapping an image
>   onto an object and you don't want the texture to tile. UV coordinates
>   will be clamped to the range 0...1. When UVs are larger than 1 or
>   smaller than 0, the last pixel at the border will be used. See Also:
>   Texture.wrapMode, texture assets.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The texture mode is already set to 'repeat'. Could it be anything else in the texture properties?

Comment: What values are being used for the offsets and what sorts of values are you getting from your camera x position?